# Want to Replace Table with Div

Tags: html, css, mpdf

I have an issue with printing HTML to Mpdf, so, I want to convert the Main Table to Div, so it works in MPDF.

I need the same layout using div

Currently this using Table

```
    <style>
        .mainTable {
            background-color: #DEDBDE;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .TdDesign {
            background-color: #F9F9F9;
            color: #000000;
            font-size: 11px;
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
        .MainTD {
            background-color: #EDEDED;
            color: #000000;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        </style>
        <table class="mainTable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0">
                            <tbody>
         <tr>
                            <td class="MainTD">Leave</td>
                            <td colspan="3" class="TdDesign">
                                    <table id="supplier" class="mainTable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                        <td class="TdDesign" width="5%" align="center"><strong>No</strong></td>
                                        <td class="TdDesign" width="10%" align="center"><strong>Type</strong></td>
                                        <td class="TdDesign" width="10%" align="center"><strong>Date</strong></td>
                                        <td class="TdDesign" width="10%" align="center"><strong>From Date</strong></td>
                                        <td class="TdDesign" width="10%" align="center"><strong>To Date</strong></td>
                                        <td class="TdDesign" width="10%" align="center"><strong>Status</strong></td>
                                        </tr></tbody></table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
        </table>
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

I need same above output but using this div, I tried but not working

```
         <style>
    .mainTable {
        background-color: #DEDBDE;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .TdDesign {
        background-color: #F9F9F9;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 11px;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }
    .MainTD {
        background-color: #EDEDED;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    </style>    
        <div class="mainTable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0">
                            <div class="MainTD">Leave
                            <div class="TdDesign">
                                    <table id="supplier" class="mainTable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                        <td class="TdDesign" width="5%" align="center"><strong>No</strong></td>
                                        <td class="TdDesign" width="10%" align="center"><strong>Type</strong></td>
                                        <td class="TdDesign" width="10%" align="center"><strong>Date</strong></td>
                                        <td class="TdDesign" width="10%" align="center"><strong>Date</strong></td>
                                        <td class="TdDesign" width="10%" align="center"><strong>To Date</strong></td>
                                        <td class="TdDesign" width="10%" align="center"><strong>Status</strong></td>
                                        </tr></tbody></table>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

I want to implement into the MPDF to print pages.

Expected result 
[image]

Comment: you can't convert html tags with css, you can change only styles with css and change the printable version with this: <link media="print" href="print.css" />

Comment: Yes, I just want to keep the same output(screenshot attached), if possible with a different style sheet, its good with div tag

Comment: you can use div tags then set display: table;
for example check this link:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#display-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution I got it

```
    <style>
    .divTable{
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .divTableRow {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
        background-color: #EEE;
        display: table-header-group;
    }
    .divTableCell, .divTableHead {
        border: 1px solid #999999;
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
        background-color: #EEE;
        display: table-header-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableFoot {
        background-color: #EEE;
        display: table-footer-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableBody {
        display: table-row-group;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="divTable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Leave</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <div class="divTable">
                    <div class="divTableCell"><strong>No</strong></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><strong>Type</strong></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><strong>Date</strong></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><strong>From Date</strong></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><strong>To Date</strong></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><strong>Status</strong></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```